# Strings to decimal in Java

Tags: android

How I can get a decimal number from string to use it for calculations and math ?
using android studio ( Java )

```
String a = "0.1234"
String b = "0.4321"
total = a * b
```

Comment: these are floating point numbers, not decimals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

`Float.valueOf(String)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do as Arju said or alternative is to parseFloat

```
float floatA = Float.parseFloat(a);
float floatB = Float.parseFloat(b);
float total = floatA*floatB;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
String a = "0.1234"
float aFloat = Float.parseFloat(a);

String b = "0.4321"
float bFloat = Float.parseFloat(b);

total = aFloat * bFloat
```

This might throw a `NumberFormatException`, so you will have to put it in a try block.